# use .try function with .map function in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to get some values from the json record and extracting like below

```
curr_json_doc['title']['genre'].map { |s| s['name'] }.join(',')
```

But for some records curr_json_doc['title']['genre'] can be blank. So I want to use try function for map and join().

I tried like below

```
curr_json_doc['title']['genre'].try(:map, { |s| s['name'] }).try(:join, (','))
```

but it didnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Please provide the *precise* error message you are getting *within the question itself*.

Answer (score 11):

You don't pass block correctly. Blocks are passed to methods outside argument parenthesis:

```
curr_json_doc['title']['genre'].try(:map) { |s| s['name'] }.try(:join, ',')
```

Comment: @rubyist You can accept this as the Answer of your Question

Answer (score 0):

Just remove empty strings and then map. You can use `delete_if` to remove the spaces.

```
curr_json_doc['title']['genre'].delete_if(&:empty?).map {|s| s['name'] }.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array()` if you are unsure if an array, a single item or nil is returned:

```
Array(curr_json_doc['title']['genre']).map { |s| s['name'] }.join(',')
```

Please note: this changes slighly the behaviour, because it returns an empty string instead of `nil` if `curr_json_doc['title']['genre']` is `nil`.